# Clean up QByteArray from \0

Tags: string, qt, arrays

In my app I use `QByteArray` to read binary data from file to a byte record with fixed size. Actually all these records are strings. If the string size less then record size so the rest of bytes are filled with \0. Sometimes the record can start with \0 too.

Example, what I need to do:

Before

```
\0 \0 \0 T h e \32 s t r i n g \0 \0 \0
```

After

```
T h e \32 s t r i n g
```

So my question - how can I clean up `QByteArray` from all of \0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this code and it's seems to work thanks to the `QByteArray & QByteArray::replace(...)` function.

```
QByteArray array;
array[0] = '\0';
array[1] = 'a';
array[2] = '\0';
array[3] = 'b';
array[4] = '\0';

qDebug() << "string:" << QString(array.toHex());
array.replace('\0',"");

qDebug() << "string:" << QString(array.toHex());
```

output:

```
string: "0061006200" 
string: "6162"
```